# router.php no servidor interno não funciona corretamente

Tags: php

Criei um arquivo router.php na raiz publica do meu projeto, esse arquivo foi feito conforme orientação na documentação do PHP para o servidor embutido. Ele funciona como uma alteranativa ao .htaccess que não tem suporte pelo servidor embutido.

```
<?php

if (preg_match('/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|js|css|)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    return false;
} else {
    include __DIR__ . '/index.php';
}
```

Quando eu uso o comando:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8888 public/router.php
```

para iniciar meu servidor, ele não carrega o CSS e os javascripts apresentando o erro:

> Not Found
>
> The requested resource /assets/css/bootstrap.min.css was not found on this server.

Alguem já passou por uma situação parecida?

Estou usando o php7.1 no Windows mas já fiz testes com a versão 5.6 e acontece a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente você deve rodar o servidor dentro da pasta public evitando usar o public/router.php:

```
cd public
php -S 127.0.0.1:8888 router.php
```

Ou iniciar com um document root alternativo:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8888 -t public/ public/router.php
```

E também, quando o servidor é iniciado em uma porta diferente esse erro pode acontecer se as URLs presentes na página forem absolutas e não incluirem a porta no endereço do recurso solicitado. Por exemplo:

```
http://127.0.0.1/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

ao invés de:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Comment: Sim, eu sei disso, mas a URL de referência dos arquivos está com a porta:
<link href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

E o erro acontece mesmo chamando o caminho completo do arquivo (Que está lá)
http://127.0.0.1:8888/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, testei aqui e parece estar relacionado ao diretório de inicialização do servidor.

Comment: Tentei fazer isso também. Não adiantou

Comment: Deu certo. fazendo o comando dentro da pasta public apontando para um arquivo rounte.php nesse diretório deu certo. Unica coisa ruim é que não queria deixar esse arquivo na pasta public, mas não tem problema. Obrigado!!!

Comment: Beleza, você pode iniciar o servidor com um diretorio root diferente tipo: php -S localhost:8888 -t public/ public/route.php